# How do you determine the length of the string in an OUTPUT_DEBUG_STRING_INFO?

Tags: winapi

The documentation for the [OUTPUT_DEBUG_STRING_INFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-output_debug_string_info) structure doesn't explain, how to determine the length (or size) of the string value it points to. Specifically, the documentation for `nDebugStringLength` is confusing:

> The lower 16 bits of the length of the string in bytes. As nDebugStringLength is of type WORD, this does not always contain the full length of the string in bytes.
>
> For example, if the original output string is longer than 65536 bytes, this field will contain a value that is less than the actual string length in bytes.

As I understand it, the true size can be any value that's a solution to the equation:

> ```
> size = nDebugStringLength + (n * 65536)
> ```

for any `n` in `[0..65536)`.

#### Question:

How do I determine the correct size of the string? Unless I'm overlooking something, the documentation appears to be insufficient in this regard.

Comment: Well, in the case where it's more than 64k bytes I'd imagine you'd have to keep reading in chunks until you find the NULL terminator. But what are you gonna do with a string longer than 64k bytes anyway? Does it even support strings that large? In older versions of Windows [the buffer is only 4k](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/outputdebugstring.html) bytes so maybe it's not even relevant.

Comment: @luk Where did you find the information that the string were NUL terminated?

Comment: Try some experimentation. I doubt you'll find any solid documentation on it.

Comment: if use `WaitForDebugEvent[Ex]` - no way. internally this api use `DbgUiConvertStateChangeStructure` for convert from `DBGUI_WAIT_STATE_CHANGE` to `DEBUG_EVENT`. the `DbgExceptionStateChange` with *ExceptionCode* `DBG_PRINTEXCEPTION_C` and `DBG_PRINTEXCEPTION_WIDE_C` converted to `OUTPUT_DEBUG_STRING_INFO` and string length **truncated** . only use native api is way here

Comment: Just tested on Windows 10. `WaitForDebugEvent` works fine when using `OutputDebugStringA`. The `nDebugStringLength` parameter is meaningless when the string is longer than 64k, but if you loop over `ReadProcessMemory` until reaching a NULL terminator then it will work as expected.

Comment: @Luke - can be no NULL terminator

Comment: `nDebugStringLength = (WORD)ExceptionRecord.ExceptionInformation[0]` (in case `DBG_PRINTEXCEPTION_C`). so if `ExceptionInformation[0] > MAXWORD` - information is lost. if use `WaitForDebugEvent[Ex]`. as is

Comment: @RbMm I think that's only true if you don't use the APIs to generate the debug string event. In any event, we're talking about strings longer than 64k bytes (or characters?). Nobody in their right mind will want to write or read messages that long so it's reasonable to cap it at something more manageable.

Comment: @luk If I were the consumer I wouldn't bother supporting more than 32k Unicode code units. But I'm not. I'm writing library code.

Comment: @Luke - yes, agree. if we will use `OutputDebugString` or `DbgPrint` (even `DbgPrompt`) string will be 0 terminated. but possible and direct call `RaiseException`. really no big sense (in debugger) output string data longer than several KB. even 64kb too long already i think. but formally data lost if use win32 api instead ntapi. here question - in what is problem or this is pure theoretical question

Comment: @IInspectable Well, part of writing a library is making choices. The underlying platform simply doesn't give you the information you need, so you have to choose how to best handle it.

Comment: @Luke - *The underlying platform* - but exist choice which platform use. if use `DbgUiWaitStateChange` (or `NtWaitForDebugEvent` ) we have much more power compare `WaitForDebugEvent` , especially in some cases.  and no info lost in this case

Comment: I think dealing with the API limitation is reasonable given that 1) the alternative is using the private, undocumented, and unsupported internal API, 2) the only way the string won't be NULL terminated is if software uses its own custom OutputDebugString implementation, and 3) we're talking about 64k byte strings. Just use the existing API, cap it at 4k bytes (as the old-style OutputDebugString does), and NULL-terminate it if it doesn't contain a NULL terminator. If you're writing 64k byte debug messages then you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @luk I'm not concerned about tradeoffs just yet. I'm concerned about how to read the documentation.

Comment: *how read documentation* - in this case exactly *The lower 16 bits of the length of the string in bytes.*

Comment: Including or excluding a NUL terminator? I mean, I just don't understand what's wrong with the Debug API's documentation. It's like every single documentation entry is complete garbage. Doesn't anyone use this API? Is Microsoft ever going to re-introduce a way for use to report issues? As it stands, this API is completely useless, and we have no way to let Microsoft know. And management just goes: "Wow, another week with zero issues reported in the Windows API repository. We totally rock!"

Comment: **Including** a NUL terminator.

Comment: Documentation is hard. You can make try submitting feedback in the [source repository](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sdk-api/blob/docs/sdk-api-src/content/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-output_debug_string_info.md).

Comment: @luk You cannot open an issue from the GitHub repository. Neither can you provide feedback from the rendered documentation page. And while I agree that writing good documentation is hard, writing sufficient documentation is an almost mechanical process.

Comment: @IInspectable You **can** provide feedback in the rendered documentation page. Choose `No` where it asks `Is this page helpful?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

initially the debug event comes in the form [`DBGUI_WAIT_STATE_CHANGE`](https://github.com/processhacker/phnt/blob/master/ntdbg.h#L187)

if use `WaitForDebugEvent[Ex]` api - it internally convert [`DBGUI_WAIT_STATE_CHANGE`](https://github.com/processhacker/phnt/blob/master/ntdbg.h#L187) to `DEBUG_EVENT` by using [`DbgUiConvertStateChangeStructure[Ex]`](https://github.com/processhacker/phnt/blob/master/ntdbg.h#L348)

the *DbgExceptionStateChang* ( in *NewState*) event with `DBG_PRINTEXCEPTION_WIDE_C` and `DBG_PRINTEXCEPTION_C` (in *ExceptionCode*) converted to `OUTPUT_DEBUG_STRING_INFO`. the *nDebugStringLength* is taken from *Exception.ExceptionRecord.ExceptionInformation[0]* or from *ExceptionInformation[3]* (in case `DBG_PRINTEXCEPTION_C` and api version without *Ex* ). but because *nDebugStringLength* is only 16 bit length, when original value is 32/64 bit length - it truncated - only low 16 bit of *ExceptionInformation[0]* (or *[3]*) is used.
note that *ExceptionInformation[0]* (and *[3]* in case `DBG_PRINTEXCEPTION_WIDE_C` ) containing string length in **characters**, **including** terminating 0.
in contrast *nDebugStringLength* in bytes (if we using `WaitForDebugEventEx` and `DBG_PRINTEXCEPTION_WIDE_C` exception - `nDebugStringLength = (WORD)(ExceptionInformation[0] * sizeof(WCHAR))`